# Fabric's `Answers Custom Event` is not working before closing the app - Android

Tags: android, google-fabric, fabric-answers

I have a function which gets called before you close the app or remove it from recent tasks. To create the custom event, I am using Fabric's `CustomEvent`.

I am getting events from other screens where app is in the foreground but I don't receive any even before closing the app.

`clearApplicationData()` gets called before app is closed.

Please refer the below code:

```
public void clearApplicationData(Context context, String clearedFrom) 
{

    Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("CLEAR_EVENT")
            .putCustomAttribute("Data cleared from", clearedFrom));
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: If you were to enable debug mode (https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html) and attempted to close the app to call that method, do you see any reference to that event being logged?